# Lua: mupltiple conditions checking

Tags: if-statement, lua, conditional-statements, return, return-value

My goal is to create a function that checks for a set of conditions and returns false if even one of those conditions isn't true. This is my attempt, but it doesn't work

```
function UnitScan:validate_cond()
    local valid = true
    if (not condition_1) then
        valid = false
        return
    end 
    -- ...
    if (not condition_n) then
        valid = false
        return
    end
    return valid
end
```

Comment: why not just use `and` like `return condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3`

Answer (score 4):

You're returning nothing (`return`) rather than returning `valid`, which you set to `false`. In terms of truthiness this doesn't matter though (`nil` is falsey as well, and none will become `nil` if used as an expression).

However, Lua already has a construct for your purpose: The `and` operator, which short-circuits, only evaluating its right side if its left side is true.

Thus your function can be rewritten as:

```lua
function UnitScan:validate_cond()
    return cond_1 and ... and cond_n
end
```

if one of your conditions doesn't return a boolean, but you want to force coercion to a boolean, wrap this as `not not (...)`.